# Windows 10 cant boot after installing Solus os

Tags: linux, windows-10

I recently installed windows 10 using the free upgrade and decided to get the new solus os. It was my first time installing an os and I followed the instructions provided.

Now, I cannot boot windows at all, the windows boot manager option is no longer showing. And when I try to access the Windows folder through solus. I get the unable to access "windows8_os" and something about the ntfs partition being in an unsafe state. I've searched everywhere for a solution but haven't found one. Can any one please help... Its urgent

Comment: Installing an OS which is not officially released yet (Solus is now in RC1 stage) is asking for trouble. Does it even support multiboot with Windows?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this only if you know you're using MBR.**

1. Use your recovery disk or if you don't have one, get an installation
   disk.
2. Restart your computer and follow the instructions that appear on the screen. 
   Go to troubleshooting and use console to type `bootsect /nt60 drive_letter: /mbr`, where "drive_letter" is the drive you have Windows installed on.
3. Restart your computer.

It should automatically boot into Windows. This is the first thing you should try, there are other solutions but this should fix it. I had a similar problem yesterday and this command fixed it (although it depends on your drive). Hopefully it'll fix yours as well.

And remember to backup regularly. I've learned this the hard way. Although in your case you haven't really lost yours, it's just inaccessible.

Comment: Better try automatic repair first. The system might be using GPT, so using the MBR option might not be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning, I kinda warned him at the end. Guess I should put it on top.

Answer (score 1):

#### Repair the Windows 10 bootloader

1. Just before the blue Windows logo appearance press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd>. Your device will restart automatically.

   [image: Windows 10 boot logo]
2. The same as in step 1, before the blue Windows logo appearance press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> once more.
3. Now, the computer will reboot again. This time let the machine restart without doing anything else.
4. The *Preparing automatic repair*, *Diagnose* and *Attempting Repairs* alerts should be displayed.
5. Click *Advanced options*.
6. Click *Troubleshoot*.
7. If you don't see the *Startup Settings* option, click *Advanced options* again.
8. Click *Startup Settings*.
9. Click *Restart*.
10. On the *Startup Settings* screen, choose the startup setting you want.

This will enable you to boot into Windows 10.

---

#### Disable Fast Startup

Disable Fast Startup in Windows 10 in order to prevent Windows 10 from being unable to boot again. With Fast Startup disabled Windows 10 will take longer to boot, but it should be able boot in less than one minute.

Fast Startup is enabled by default in Windows 10. If Fast Startup is enabled, Windows 10 does not actually completely shutdown when you choose shutdown. Instead, it does a "hybrid shutdown". This is something like hibernating, it makes booting Windows 10 back up faster, but it also prevents mounting the Windows partition when Windows has not been shutdown properly.

To disable Fast Startup, boot into Windows 10 and follow these steps:

1. Open Control Panel in the Small icons view and click *Power Options*.
2. In the pane on the left side, click *Choose what the power buttons do*.
3. Click *Change settings that are currently unavailable*.
4. Uncheck *Turn on fast startup (recommended)*.
5. Click the *Save changes* button.
6. Shutdown Windows 10 and boot back into SolusOS.
7. If you still aren't able to mount without getting errors, turn off hibernation completely. Open an elevated cmd prompt. In the search box inside the Windows 10 Start menu type `cmd` and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch an elevated command prompt. Run the following command to turn off hibernation completely:

   ```
   powercfg /h off
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Just update the grub...

type `sudo update-grub`

it happens after updating kernel

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.